# Variable initialized as a constant in C++

Tags: c++, string, variables, console

In the code below, the variable gender is initialized as a constant, but the compiler is giving an error that invalid conversion of const char data type to char data type.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //initializing the variable
    int a;
    //declaring the variable
    a = 13;
    //data type: character, keyword: char, max size: 8 bits (1 byte)
    char gender;
    gender="Male";
    cout<<"This is character data type: "<<gender<<endl;
    //data type: integer, keyword: int, max size: 16 bits (2 bytes), range: -2^15-2^15 (-32768-32767)
    int age = 19;
    cout<<"This is int data type:"<<age<<endl;
    //data type: integer, keyword: short int, max size: 16 bits (2 bytes), range: -2^15-2^15 (-32768-32767)
    short int no = 12;
    cout<<"This is short int data type: "<<no<<endl;
    //data type: integer, keyword: long int, max size: 32 bits (4 bytes), range: -2^31-2^31 (-2147483648-2147483647)
    long int larger = 21233487;
    cout<<"This is long int data type: "<<larger<<endl;
    //data type: floating point, keyword: float, max size: 32 bits (4 bytes)
    float ab = 9.7;
    cout<<"This is a floating point data type decimal: "<<ab<<endl;
    //data type: floating point, keyword: double, max size: 64 bits (8 byte)
    double ac = 1232434.7666;
    cout<<"This is a double data type decimal:"<<ac<<endl;
    //data type: floating point, keyword: long double, max size: 80 bits (10 byte)
    long double ad = 1233284.79872;
    cout<<"This is a long double data type decimal:"<<ad<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

> C:\Users\Abdullah\Desktop\C++\Fundamentals\03_Variables and Data
> Types.cpp [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'
> [-fpermissive]

I have tried initializing the variable in one line and declaring it in another, but nothing changed. I went through all the code but found nothing that was producing an error.

Comment: You declared it as a single-character type, so you can write:

`char gender = 'm';`

To make it multi-character, you need to use an array type:

`const char* gender = "Male";`

Comment: A side note: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring gender as a character datatype. '**char**' can only store **1 character**. To fix this, modify the declaration to this.

```
const char *gender;
gender = "Male";
```

OR

```
const char *gender = "Male";
```

You will probably still get a warning but the code will work fine now.

Comment: `const char *`, it should be

Comment: @PaulSanders yeah you are right it should be const char*

Comment: Thanks, yeah the code is running and there is no warning also.

Answer (score 0):

```
char gender[] = "Male";
```

Use this line instead of char gender; gender="Male", it will form a char array/pointer.